# Exception in main thread when executing java jar file with pdfbox

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, pdfbox

I use JRE 1.7 with pdfbox 2.0.4 and when I execut the jar file (built with Eclipse) I get the below error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

I use the following Class-Path in the file manifest.mf

Class-Path: lib/pdfbox-2.0.4.jar lib/pdfbox-app-2.0.4.jar lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar

The content of jar file :

```
\.classpath
\.project
\bin
\jtd
\lib
\META-INF
\pom.xml
\bin\jtd
\bin\jtd\sign.class
\jtd\sign.class
\lib\commons-logging-1.2.jar
\lib\pdfbox-2.0.4.jar
\lib\pdfbox-app-2.0.4.jar
\lib\pdfbox-tools-2.0.4.jar
\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF
```

Comment: the class name is fine. are you sure the jar files are located as specified in the manifest?

Comment: Path names are relative to the location of the jar file.

Comment: I have solved my problem by copying the jar files in a \lib subfolder in the same directory as my jar file . Thanks for your help

Comment: @Raph I suggest you answer this yourself with your comment, or that you press the green checkmark on the answer of "upf" if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem by copying the jar files in a \lib subfolder in the same directory as my jar file

Answer (score 0):

When exporting to a "Runnable JAR file" in eclipse, you should mark "Package required libraries into generated JAR". 
Saves me from a lot of trouble... :)